# Update the 'invalid edit' audits?

Tags: feature-request, review-audits

1. The audits for 'invalid edits' always have the same pattern: randomly inserted texts
2. They take a long time to load (5-10 seconds) instead of the almost instantaneous 'next'.

This means somebody trying to game the system by constantly clicking Approve will seldom be fooled and the audit loses its value.

Is there anything that can be done about this? I know of no suggestions myself.

Comment: I don't have review privileges here, but on [SO] I suggested creating new audits that add bad tags: [http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260185/create-too-minor-review-audits-that-consist-of-adding-a-bad-tag]. Maybe that would be useful for Super User as well?